# Save current location in Emacs tutorial

Tags: saving

I am learning Emacs by doing built-in tutorial (C-h t). However, when I decide to take a break and exit the editor (C-x C-c) and then later rerun the tutorial the position when I finished before is not saved. The tutorial starts over from the beginning. Is there a way to save this position so that I do not have to remember where I finished? (Well, maybe the tutorial covers the problem in some place, but I have not yet got to it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41710995/1030675

Comment: Use `C-x k` to kill the tutorial buffer when you're done, and it will offer to save your position.  (Evidentially this doesn't happen if you exit Emacs entirely with `C-x C-c`.)

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this by default is to use `C-x k` to kill the buffer, and then you will be given the option to save your position.

If you want emacs to do the same check when you use `C-x C-c` then add the following to your .emacs file.

https://pastebin.com/YWvJWVnk

By using:

```
(advice-add 'help-with-tutorial :override
(defun help-with-tutorial-deals-with-c-x-c-c (...)
```

it adds the line:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions 'tutorial--save-tutorial nil t)
```

to the function `help-with-tutorial`, which is now called `help-with-tutorial-deals-with-x-s-x-c`